# Spark parallelization on an array of dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Environment: Scala,spark,structured streaming

If i have an array of datasets in Scala `Array(Dataset[Row])` which im interested in processing in parallel using a function that processes a `Dataset[Row]`  object, is it enough to pass the array object through a map or foreach to utilize sparks parallelism in a spark cluster?

EDIT: i have stumbled on a few issues, i will re-explain the question in another thread

Answer (score 1):

I have taken simple example to process in parallel.

You need to write function as per your requirement, Check below code for sample.

To see parallel effect try launch your spark shell using - `spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 3`

```
scala> val dsList = Seq(Seq(1,2).toDS,Seq(4).toDS,Seq(7,9).toDS,Seq(10).toDS)
```

```
scala> dsList.par.reduce(_ union _).show(false)
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|1    |
|2    |
|4    |
|7    |
|9    |
|10   |
+-----+
```

```
scala> dsList.par.foreach(_.show(false))
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|1    |
|2    |
+-----+

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|4    |
+-----+

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|7    |
|9    |
+-----+

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|10   |
+-----+
```

Comment: Par looks like a scala builtin function, id like to repartition the data so spark could for example send 3 elements of the data to one worker and the rest to another worker

Comment: yes, you can use repartition inside ```map``` function something like - ```dsList.par.map(ds => ds.repartition(..))```

Comment: Ok im having some unrelated problems with the spark cluster so il pick an answer after i will resolve the issue.

Comment: Ok i tried it , didnt work, all the data was processed in the driver, from what read what i want is Some sort of a nested rdd which spark does not support..

Comment: I tried your code,it worked on the driver but  i viewed on my spark cluster that only the driver was activated, and no parallelization was happening on the cluster level

Comment: As per your request : arrayofseq :Seq[Dataset[Row]] ;                           ```arrayofseq.par.map(ds=> ds.repartition(1)).foreach(_.show)```

Comment: how you launched your spark shell ??

Comment: use this command to launch spark shell - spark-shell --master yarn --num-executors 3 & check in spark web ui.

Comment: I use spark submit with --deploy-mode cluster, i dont use yarn

Comment: There are 2, an example of  working parallelization is a single Dataframe with multiple rows, code: ```df.repartition(5).foreach(function)``` however each object is a row object and im not familiar with manipulating it

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question

*is it enough to pass the array object through a map or foreach to utilize sparks parallelism in a spark cluster?*

is no. For map and foreach to work, you must collect the data into one node.

Why not turn the Array(Dataset[Row]) into a Dataframe?

If you want to run a function on data row by row, you can use a UDF. Works like a charm!

Comment: Im preforming heavy computation on each row and would like to parallelise this process to speed it up, i dont need to collect the data, just to send the data to a function in parallel, will udf do the trick?

Comment: Yes! Take a look at UDFs, which are designed to apply functions to data row by row. They are pretty well documented on spark.apache.org.